# Changing hardness/size of a brush on a wacom tablet does not work

Tags: adobe-photoshop, wacom

My Wacom tablet does not cooperate when I want to change hardness/size of my brush in photoshop.

It works with mouse and shortcuts on keyboard, but when I use alt and click the button on my pen (which is set to be a "right-click") and then I press it onto the tablet surface and go up and down to change these values it just keeps showing eye-dropper tool as if the right-click was not decteded, just alt.(then I press button on my pen to check if the right-click is waroking at all, and it is. The problem seems to be when I press alt and then a button on my pen).

I checked my wacom settings and they are deafault:

tip - one click
button closer to the tip - right-click
second button - double-click

It worked in the past...do you know what else to check to see why is it not working at all or me now?

Comment: Can somebody clarify why was this put on hold? Did I repeat the question or something?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the Wacom drivers may fix the problem.

Comment: Tried it, but did not help, unfortunately.

Comment: Does your pen has batteries? you may have to change the battery.

Comment: Nope , no batteries. It's intuos5.